# How to return Logcat window to Debug window?

Tags: intellij-idea

I've removed a LogCat window from a Debug window in IDEA 11 and I cannot find a way to return it there. This is how my debug window now looks.

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you're just trying to find it in the menu hierarchy, it's View - Tool Windows - Android Monitor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try Restore Layout button.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the window header as in eclipse, instead drag the tab itself

[image: where to drag]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what you mean with *return Logcat window to Debug window*, that is if logcat's output can actually appear into Debug tool window.

If you want back the Android tool window just click its button, it's the first button in the lower row of the image you pasted.